# PHP int 64 bit turns scientific notation way below its maximum value

Tags: php, int, 64-bit, biginteger, scientific-notation

My PHP environment is 64 bit:

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
    9223372036854775807
```

So I thought I could operate with integer values lower than PHP_INT_MAX value.

But this code:

```
echo (517002.962 * 1000000000);
```

gives this result:

```
5.17002962E+14
```

So, I am confused. If 5.17002962E+14 is lower than PHP_INT_MAX (9223372036854775807), **why does PHP convert it to scientific notation?**

Comment: float * integer = float

Comment: Thx. I think you are right!

Comment: PS: Unless you using PHP7 then even 64 bit PHP does not actually support true 64bit integers

Comment: Whatever you do, if the accuracy of these calculations matter then you should really consider the [BC Math Library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)

Comment: @PaulCrovella Yup you are right, aplogise profusely. There, I have been exposed as a Windows User. How will I ever live it down! :) My _Street cred is destroyed_ :)  :(